# Is a transit visa required for a 2-hour stopover in Dublin?

Tags: transit

Does a Papua New Guinea passport holder require a transit visa for a 2-hour stopover in Dublin on the way through to Edinburgh?

Comment: Note that a “stopover” usually means a stop of over 24 hours during which you get at of the airport and spend at least one night in the country. For a short duration connection where you don’t leave the airport, one usually says “stop” or “layover”.

Comment: Also, it may be relevant to know if both flights are booked on the same ticket and/or if you have hold luggage. If you have hold luggage and the flights are on separate tickets, you will usually need to go through immigration, pick up your bags, go through customs and check your luggage back in before proceeding through security and on to your gate. This may affect your need for a visa.

Answer (score 1):

From the Republic of Ireland site [Department of Foreign Affairs and Trade](https://www.dfa.ie/travel/visas/visas-for-ireland/) listing visas for Ireland, under `Requirements` the link to the Irish Naturalisation and Immigration Service [Check if you need a visa](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/check-irish-visa) will answer your question.

Selecting `Papua New Guinea` for `What nationality is shown on your passport or travel document?`, and then selecting `Transit through Ireland. eg via an Irish airport` for `How long do you want to stay in Ireland?`, gives the result:

> **You do not need a transit visa**
>
> You do not need a transit visa to travel through an Irish airport on
>   your way to another destination.

Note that if you actually wanted to be a tourist in Ireland you *would* need a visa.

Answer (score 0):

Ireland and UK have an immigration agreement, the flight from Dublin to Edinburgh will be deal like a domestic flight